# dropping a particle into a vector field, part 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Okay, so I've been independently trying to study basic systems of differential equations as they relate to dropping a particle into a vector field.  I have had two previous posts on the matter trying to intuitively understand what is happening in these cases.  The posts can be found here "[dropping a particle into a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497740/dropping-a-particle-into-a-vector-field)" and here "[dropping a particle into a vector field, part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498108/dropping-a-particle-into-a-vector-field-part-2)".
So without looking up methods to solving them, I've been able to solve some very basic problem.  For example, if I have $$\mathbf{F}(x,y)=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$$
I calculated that at any point $(a,b)$ where I drop my particle at $t=0$, then the path the particle traces over $t$ is $\mathbf{r}(t)=(e^t-1+a)\mathbf{i}+(e^t-1+b)\mathbf{j}$.  Similarly, if my vector field is defined by
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y)=x\mathbf{i}-y\mathbf{j}$$
Then $\mathbf{r}(t)=(e^t-1+a)\mathbf{i}+(e^{-t}-1+b)\mathbf{j}$ for the same conditions at $\mathbf{r}(0)$ at point $(a,b)$.

Now, I tried a different field defined by 
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y)=(x+y)\mathbf{i}+(x-y)\mathbf{j}$$
However, here I get the system
$$\mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{y}(t)$$
$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)$$
If I differentiate the first equation i get
$$\mathbf{x}''(t)=\mathbf{x}'(t)+\mathbf{y}'(t)$$
$$=\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{y}(t)+\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)$$
$$=2\mathbf{x}(t)$$
Now with a little intuition I figured that a possible solution for $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is $e^{t\sqrt{2}}$
This implies by substitution that
$$\mathbf{y}(t)=\sqrt{2}e^{t\sqrt{2}}-e^{t\sqrt{2}}$$
so
$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=2e^{t\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}e^{t\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=e^{t\sqrt{2}}+e^{t\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}e^{t\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=e^{t\sqrt{2}}-(\sqrt{2}e^{t\sqrt{2}}-e^{t\sqrt{2}})$$
$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)$$
So it works? So is this method of differentiating members of the system work for "simple" fields?  basic fields with linear terms?

Comment: You have ended up with a second-order equation for $x$, so you should write down a solution with two unknown constants.  However, since your force field is linear in $x,y$, linear algebra gives a simpler and more general approach to these types of systems...

Comment: Okay.  I was trying to do a couple of easy ones without the linear algebra and what was described In the second post a matrix exponential.  But I guess it's onto linear algebra!

Comment: You're doing great w/ your self-study. Note that $x''=2x$ is solved by $x(t)=C{\rm e}^{\sqrt{2}t}$ - you have picked $C=1$. You're also missing a constant upon integrating the ODE for $y$, do you see where? Btw, please do post another problem where you try to work w/ linear algebra for more general linear ODEs, I'd love to see how you deal w/ those.